# Closing python MySQL script

Tags: python, mysql, while-loop

I was wondering if one of you could advice me how to tackle a problem I am having. I developed a python script that updates data to a database (MySQL) every iteration (endless while loop). What I want to prevent is that if the script is accidentally closed or stopped half way the script it waits till all the data is loaded into the database and the MySQL connection is closed (I want this to prevent incomplete queries). Is there a way to tell the program to wait till the loop is done before it closes?

I hope this all makes sense, feel free to ask questions.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are asking for a way by which if someone presses ctrl+c or ctrl+z the program should not stop execution till it completes all the data insertion.

There are two approach to it.

1) Insert all the data into the database by enabling transaction. When transaction is enabled until you commit the data will not be inserted. So you can commit once all the datas are entered and incase if some one closes the application the transaction will not be commited.

2) You can trap the interrupt signals of ctrl+c and ctrl+z and thus your program still runs uninterrupted. [This](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/signal.html) would help.

Answer (score 2):

There are some things you can do to prevent a program from being closed unexpectedly (signal handlers, etc), but they only work in some cases and not others.  There is always the chance of a system shutdown, power failure or SIGKILL that will terminate your program whether you like it or not.  The canonical solution to this sort of problem is to use database transactions.

If you do your work in a transaction, then the database will simply roll back any changes if your script is interrupted, so you will not have any incomplete queries.  The worst that can happen is that you need to repeat the query from the beginning next time.

Answer (score 0):

Use with statement.  Some examples [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Define some exception handler. Like:

```
class Cursor(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 username,
                 password
                 ):
        # init your connection here

    def __iter__(self):
        # for reading content of cursor

    def __enter__(self):
        # something executed before establish connection

    def __exit__(self, ext_type, exc_value, traceback):
        # something executed when there is an error or connection finishes

with Cursor() as cursor:
    print(cursor)
    connection = (cursor.connection)
    print(connection)
```